# In my AWS, codebuild build, I get an error 'No artifact files specified' when I try to specify my endpoint in my yml file.

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yaml, aws-codebuild

I have googled and searched within stackoverflow and found some suggestions but still no succedd. My build process in AWS Codebuild runs and gives me a success output but in the log shows -> 'No artifact files specified', and as the result no files are being copied in my S3. Could anybody help me figure this out. Here I share my yml setting:

```
version: 0.1
phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Nothing to do yet
addons:
  artifacts:
    s3_region: "eu-central-1"
    files:
      - '**/*'
```

Comment: CodeBuild does not support s3_region flag http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html. It will use region where you are running the build instead.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you refer to the [Build Specification Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html).

Specifically, you should remove `addons:` as well as `s3_region:` as neither of these are valid CodeBuild flags. You should also be using `version: 0.2`, as `version: 0.1` has been deprecated.

Here is what your `buildspec.yml` should look like:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Nothing to do yet

artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
```